# How to accept xml file in vaadin

Tags: vaadin

Hello as i am new to vaadin i need help in accepting xml file in vaadin application.
More detail specification is as such : 
The android mobile sends the xml file, which has to be retrieved in vaadin application. I doesn't know how to accept xml file in vaadin application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the Vaadin Upload components: http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#Uploads

For this case, the BasicUpload component example should be sufficient. When using the upload component, you'll need to provide your own definition of the Receiver required by the Upload constructor. In this class's receiveUpload method, you can write the XML file to memory or a database.